# Recovering alternate solutions to a discrete logarithm that can be attacked using Pohlig-Hellman

Tags: discrete-logarithm, pohlig-hellman

In the process of studying discrete logarithms and approaches that could be taken, I saw the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm.

Later when I was working with $h = g^x \mod p$ where $p-1$ is smooth, using Pohlig-Hellman did not give the expected result, and returned something much larger than expected. I assume this is because Pohlig-Hellman skips over the smallest answer occasionally.

Questions:

1. How can I recover the smallest possible $x$ correctly?
2. I have the larger $x$; could that be used to recover a smaller $x'$?

Comment: Did you see [Pohlig–Hellman algorithm : General algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm#The_general_algorithm)

Comment: @kelalaka I read through that. It looks like the general how-to-use the algorithm. I dont see how that allows for alternate solutions however. Can you point me towards what Im supposed to look at?

Comment: The smallest would be $x \bmod{(p-1)}$ if $p$ is prime

Comment: All the solutions are part of an equivalence class given by $\bmod (p-1)$. So $x' = x \bmod (p-1)$. That said, the final step in the PH algo is to combine solutions in subgroups using the Chinese Remainder Theorem & the solution would be in the form $x = something \bmod (p-1)$. So you will always end up with the smallest solution. Could you list your different subgroup solutions which you combine with the CRT?

Comment: @user93353 I ended up solving it from your message. Thanks!